# Using Hydra Configuration inside Classes

Tags: python, configuration, fb-hydra

I am trying to use the hydra tool in my project and would like to use the decorator for class functions

```py
import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore

from src.config import RecordingConfig

cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(name="recording_config", node=RecordingConfig)

class HydraClassTest:
    @hydra.main(config_path="../src/conf/", config_name="conf")
    def __init__(self, conf: RecordingConfig):
        print(conf)

def main():
    HydraClassTest()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I get the error

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'conf'
```

Is this intended and should I pass the configuration from the outside to the class? (For example by using the decorator on the main function and passing the configuration as a parameter to the initializer, this works)
Or am using the decorator in a wrong way?
If it is intended, is there some design reason why one would not want to do it that way?

I have checked whether I used the decorator correctly by passing the configuration through the main function, that worked.

```py
import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore

from src.config import RecordingConfig

cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(name="recording_config", node=RecordingConfig)

class HydraClassTest:
    def __init__(self, conf: RecordingConfig):
        print(conf)

@hydra.main(config_path="../src/conf/", config_name="conf")
def main(conf: RecordingConfig):
    HydraClassTest(conf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This gives me the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@hydra.main()` is not appropriate for this use case. It's designed to be used once in an application and it has many side effects (changing working directory, configuring logging etc).

Use the [Compose API](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/compose_api/) instead.